# Using Instagram API to push image to the app from a site on a mobile browser

Tags: image, mobile, instagram, push

I would like to know if it could be possible to push an image from a mobile website to the Instagram app using Instagram's API?

This would be similar to pushing an image from a 3rd party app to the Instagram app for uploading. For example this is what instasize does, but I would like to do it from a web site.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to directly load an image in Instagram from a mobile website.

You could have users save the image, then use Instagram's [Custom URL Scheme](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#custom-url-scheme) to bring up the camera (`instagram://camera`) and then have them select the photo library from there. This would only work in iOS though.

Otherwise, if you want to load an image in Instagram, you'd need to do it from a native app. Perhaps it could be possible this way using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) or something similar? There's more info on the [iPhone Hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/) page of the Instagram Developer Documentation.